# WiFi inoperative ONLY when automatically connecting to VPN (18.04)

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I connect to WiFi. **Internet works**.

Then I manually connect to a VPN with `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` package (ie: top right corner VPN menu). **Internet works**.

I set up "Automatically connect to VPN" with `nm-connection-editor` and restart. **Internet does not work**.

I disconnect from the VPN manually. **Internet does not work**.

I deselect "Automatically connect to VPN" and reboot. **Internet works**.

---

I am using the exact same `ovpn` files on other computers with no issues. Any ideas on why this is happening (specific to this laptop)?

---

**Sample OVPN config**

```
client
dev tun
proto udp 
remote us-ga.gw.ivpn.net 2049
auth-user-pass

resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-tun
persist-key
persist-remote-ip

cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-DSS-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name us-ga name-prefix
key-direction 1
comp-lzo
verb 3

script-security 2
setenv PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
up /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
down-pre

;ca ca.crt
```